# How do you use Framer Motion + Styled Components together?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, framer-motion

I’m wanting to use Styled Components and Framer Motion Together to style and animate....
Can I use a variable from SC or FM  to style and animate it?

What is a example?

Comment: Yes, you can, what you want to style exactly? Please elaborate, show some code examples. You have `styled-components` examples in framer-docs, what answer do you expect?

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to use styled function as a HOC for any motion component

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const AnimatedDiv = styled(motion.div)`
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
`;
```

This allows you to use the Component as such:

```js
<AnimatedDiv animate={{ scale: 3 }} />
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still don’t want to be adding the animated syntax in the created element/tag. I want to have it working as a “variable” way

Comment: Would you want to elaborate what a "variable" way would actually look like?

Answer (score 3):

The best method is to use the `as` prop:

```
<StyledComponent as={motion.div}/>
```

This maintains the `framer-motion` intent of "variability" as you put it, in being able to easily replace DOM elements with their motion counterparts.

This was unusually hard to find online so I want to post it.